# How to use conditional formatting for "less than value in previous cell" in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting for cells that are less than value of a previous cell in the same column.  For example, if D5 < D4 apply formatting, if D6 < D5 apply formatting, etc down the column.

I created conditional formatting for D5 denoting D4 as =D4 to get it's value.  This works, however, when I copy this formatting to the cell below, D6, it does two things:

1. It does not make a copy of the formatting but updates existing one adding a range (D4,D5).
2. It still references D4 to check the value against, while I need it to compare against D5.

I'm not sure why D5 is always referenced, since I'm not using absolute reference, but a relative one.  I don't see a way to compare with previous cell in the same column other than creating a formatting for each cell.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution based on another post [color red if cell above value is lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356466/color-cell-red-if-cell-above-value-is-lower?noredirect=1&lq=1):

1. Select a range where formatting needs to be applied, e.g. D9:D20.
2. Right click, select Conditional Formatting.
3. Click "Add new rule"
4. In "format cells if" choose **custom formula is**.
5. Enter formula: =D9

   Select desired formatting.

Comment: Could you elaborate where is the "previous cell" part in the solution? I thought '=D9' would format each cell from the 9-20 range depending of each respective D cell (not previous), so D9 based on D9, D10 based on D10...